# How to connect fragment and layout

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-activity, layout

I'm trying to set on click method in my project but, I can't connect my layout to the given fragment. When you press the icon of Instagram it should open persons Instagram but it only crashes.

Fragment code:

```
 public class SupportFragment extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    ImageView vedoIg;
  public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_support,container,false);
        vedoIg = v.findViewById(R.id.vedo_ig);
        vedoIg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://instagram.com/v");
                Intent instagram = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                instagram.setPackage("com.instagram.android");
                try {
                    startActivity(instagram);
                }
                catch (Exception e){
                    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://instagram.com/_u/v")));
                }
            }
        });
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_support,container,false);
    }

   }
```

Layout folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="@drawable/pozadina"
    tools:context=".SupportFragment">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:text="Contact us: "
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
    android:text="Vedo"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/vedo_ig"
    android:layout_width="72dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/w_instagram"/>
```

Any tip would mean the world. Thanks in advance  :D <3

Comment: override onViewCreated and moved your listener code.

Comment: `return v` instead of inflating again. Also, what's the stack trace?

Comment: Thank you @BenP. it worked, I just set return v. much love

Comment: @BenP. post your solution and I will like it and approve it

Comment: When the app crashes, you should be able to see the log of what is happening in the Logcat tab of Android Studio. The stack trace is the error part of that log (it will be in red). https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/stacktraces

Comment: @RedBassett ok thank you, now I will know in future :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This bit of code is problematic:

> ```
> public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_support,container,false);
>     vedoIg = v.findViewById(R.id.vedo_ig);
>     // ...
>     return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_support,container,false);
> }
> ```

In the first line, you're inflating one copy of a view... but then you `return` a different copy of that same view. This means that what the user sees won't match the view you've been searching in and setting click listeners on.

Change the last line to `return v` to fix this issue.